# A story including an alien hand in jar in a basement

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember this movie playing on the scifi channel when i was a kid, probably 2003-2006, where 6 kids go to this small town to vacation at this house that one of the kid's uncle owns. They were in college I believe.

There was a black guy, a redhead girl, a couple and a brunette as well as the main character. When they get to the house there's all this metal around it, like above the door.

They find a jar with an aliens hand in it in the basement and it twitches. The redhead goes missing first, then the black guy, then the aliens start beaming into the house and one of the guys is halfway standing on the beam and is cut in half down the middle. Finally the last three kids escape in a truck.

Comment: I'm at a loss why someone would vote to close this as "too broad". The description was excellent.

Comment: This sounds like a really weird movie. I mean, the black guy disappears *second*?

Comment: @KSmarts Well the SyFy channel (as it's known now- once SciFi) has never been known for movies that made sense (or that were any good). I did love some of their shows (Stargate!) though.

Answer (score 9):

This is "[Silent Warnings](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348031/)", a 2003 TV movie.

The film contains all the features you've mentioned including a guy getting cut in half and the discovery of an alien hand in a basement.